# Running github for windows powershell on remote server

Tags: git, powershell, ansible, powershell-remoting, github-for-windows

I'm attempting to use Ansible to automate some deployment on a remote Windows machine and am having some difficulty with executing git commands on the remote machine. If I'm physically on remote machine, I use git through the posh-git command line tool provided by the Github client for Windows. I made the git executable available from the standard powershell, by adding

```
.  (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
.  $env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1
```

to my profile in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1`.

When I try to execute git commands in a powershell script through Ansible, it appears as if the profile is not being "sourced" (using the Linux parlance that I'm much more familiar with) in the remote session. According to [these docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847857.aspx), there is a profile for "Current User, All Hosts" that is read from `$Home\Documents\Profile.ps1`, but locating the same file there doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Any ideas of how to get my environment set up properly so that I can run powershell scripts that reference the Github posh-git git command from within a powershell script executed by Ansible, which is using a python wrapper around WinRM?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell doesn't load the profile when you use remoting.

posh-git doesn't really add `git` to PowerShell, it mostly gives a custom prompt in git repos and tab completion for `git` commands. The actual git functionality is provided by [msysgit](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), so there is a `git.exe` executable around somewhere.

If you add the path (for me it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`) to your `PATH` environment variable on the remote host, or include the full path to git in your commands, it should work; so instead of `git push`, maybe do:

```
& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Git\Bin\git.exe" push
```

Not very pretty, but it should do the job. You can also make an alias:

```
New-Alias -Name git -Value "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Git\Bin\git.exe"
git push
```

But you still can't load this automatically without the profile, unless you create a new session configuration and create a new powershell endpoint, but I'm not sure if Ansible can use that. You could try to replace the configuration of the default endpoint `Microsoft.PowerShell` but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: It appears as if the version of git that is used by the "Github Shell" is actually in `<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<long hash>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to rely on a profile, I ended up just calling the line that sets up git directly in my powershell script:

```
function SetupGit () {
    Write-Host "Setting up powershell git access"

    if (Get-Command git -errorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Host "git is already accessible"
        return
    }

    .  (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")

    if (-Not (Get-Command git -errorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Host "Cannot find git command"
        Exit 1
    }
}
```